# How to use sx prop in styled components without mui

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

Instead of using multiple props for each css attribute, I want to make an `sx` prop like material-ui has. I'm trying to implement this with `styled-components`. The idea is that I can pass an object as a prop, and reference a value from the object in the styled component.

#### things to note:

- `material-ui` is not added as a dependancy. I want to "clone" sx from it.
- currently looking into `prop-types` to add some value in finding bug.

### Button Component

```js
import styled from "styled-components";

export const Button = styled.button`
  background-color: ${(sx) => sx.backgroundColor};
  color: ${(sx) => sx.color};
`;
```

### Rendering Button

```js
import React from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";
import { Button } from "./Button/Button";

function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <Button sx={{ backgroundColor: "red", color: "white" }} />
    <>
  );
}

export default App;
```

### Update:

After adding `prop-types` to maybe find the issue, I get an error when I pass the prop to the Button component when I added this code:

```js
// typechecking prop types passed
Button.propTypes = {
  sx: PropTypes.string,
};
```

And the error I got back:

```
Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `sx` of type `object` supplied to `styled.button`, expected `string`
```

Im not sure exactly where its going wrong. I've tried doing a `console.log` to see the value passed, which seems to be a `string`. Therefore dot notation should work?

#### Any help would be appreciated, thanks very much :)

Answer (score 0):

After adding `prop-types` and finding the passed types, I was able to find this answer:

```js
// required prop to be passed as an object
Button.propTypes = {
  sx: PropTypes.object,
};

// updating the props for Button component
export const Button = styled.button`
  background-color: ${(props) => props.sx.backgroundColor};
  color: ${(props) => props.sx.color};
`;
```

then using `sx` as normal...

```js
import React from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";
import { Button } from "./Button/Button";

function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <Button sx={{ backgroundColor: "red", color: "white" }} />
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```